# @Entity sends null passworld to h2 db

Tags: java, json, spring, entity

I have an unusual problem. In a row from in h2 database, the `password` is empty but the `username` isn't.

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Instructor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter
    private Long id;
    @Getter
    private String userName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instructor")
    @Getter
    private List<Course> courses;


    private String password;

    public Instructor(String name, String password){
        this.userName = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void addCourse(Course coursex){
        this.courses.add(coursex);
    }
}
```

I tried removing the `@JsonIgnore` from the password field, but it still didn't save the password in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `@Getter` annotation. That's how hibernate will serialize.